# Is Euler-characteristic of a simplicial complex on $n$ vertices and $f$ facets at most $n^{O(\log f)}$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, at.algebraic-topology, simplicial-complexes, euler-characteristics

(Definition: Facet = Maximal Face)

This question is a continuation of the previous one that I had asked a couple of years ago: [Is Euler characteristic of a simplicial complex upper bounded by a polynomial in the number of its facets ?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/91712/is-euler-characteristic-of-a-simplicial-complex-upper-bounded-by-a-polynomial-in/91842#91842)

As an answer to my previous question, David Speyer gave an example showing that the Euler characteristic of a simplicial complex need not be polynomially bounded in terms of number of its facets. He further suggested a weaker bound, which if true would come handy in my research. Hence, I am posting it as a question here.